# js issue input file button is not working, the pop up won't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsley.js

I have a problem, I validate my form with js plugin Parsley , and on pages where Parsely plugin is initiated the form input type="file" is not working, not clickable" , is see the button animates when clicked but no pop up for the file-system to pick file for upload, and the input is not validated by parserly , inputs on ALL the page where there is Parsly do not work, when I comment out the Parsley instantiation the file input works as expected, here is how I init the plugin:

```
app.Manage.BasicInfoForm.parsley(app.Manage.validatorConfig).validate();
```

before this line is executed the inputs work fine also if I have custom validators declared it will prevent file input from working as well like:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('reservednamescheck', 
                function (value, requirement) {
                      var noAllow = app.websiteManage.noAllowWebsiteNames;
                      var forbbidenName = '';
                      for (var i = noAllow.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {      
                          if (value === noAllow[i]) {
                            forbbidenName = noAllow[i];
                            return false;
                          }
                      }
                      return true;
                }, 32)
                .addMessage('en', 'reservednamescheck', 'Sorry but this name is reserved');
```

so this will prevent file input from working as well, again, even if file input is standalone anywhere on the page it does not work when Parsley is present, Please help, Thank You

Comment: have you checked your console log?

Comment: Yes , no errors displayed and everything working as expected except for the file input

Answer (score 1):

my bad, the problem was not with the plugin but with an jquery event , this code was causing the problem:

```
$(document).on('click input ', app.websiteManage.websiteNameInput , function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // detects if inputed website name accordingly changes the title
                app.websiteManage.websiteNameBind.html(app.websiteManage.websiteNameInput.val());
             });
```

so I was listening to click and preventing the default behavior , that is why my input file was not working, thank You for everyone who tried to help ;)

Comment: Haha! Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version number. The API has changed, and in the 2.0+ version, the 3rd parameter is the parsley instance.

So you would add the message inside your function, something like:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('myvalidator', {
                requirementType: 'string',
                validateMultiple: function(value, dataProp, instance) {
                    .
                    .
                    .

                    instance.reset(); // clear previous error
                    instance.addError('en', {message: 'my message here'});
                    return false;
                },
                messages: {
                    en: '...'
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thank You, the custom rule is working but the problem is that the file input is not working when parsley present on the page , I still couldn't figured it out and switched to a different plugin

Comment: Well, good. At least you got it working in the end, even if it wasn't with your original intent.